# Gparted doesn't detect available space in an LVM volume

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

I am trying to shrink my current partition so that another partition I'm using for another OS can be enlarged. I have tried this from a bootable USB and the yellow space in GParted fills the partition.

[image: used space?]

When I run `df -h`, I can see that there's 1.7 TB of available disk space. Why does GParted not detect that there is unused space in the partition, and how can I increase the size of the small partition (48gb) without reflashing the whole disk and starting again?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         13G  2.5M   13G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  1.8T   33G  1.7T   2% /
tmpfs                         63G  163M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                   145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/34
/dev/loop1                   145M  145M     0 100% /snap/code/35
/dev/loop2                    98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/loop3                    97M   97M     0 100% /snap/core/9436
/dev/loop4                    55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop5                    55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop7                   2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop6                   256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop8                    45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop9                   3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/sda1                    511M  7.3M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop10                   63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop11                   44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/415
/dev/loop12                   50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop13                  162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
tmpfs                         13G   20K   13G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                         13G   24K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/a/918346/1087371) help ?

Comment: From GParted’s perspective that space is not free. It’s in use as a physical volume that is part of a volume group. You need to work on the volume group to free up some physical space.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/how-to-reduce-volume-group-size-in-lvm) (Thanks for linking Parsa Mousavi). I needed to:

```
sudo lvresize --verbose --resizefs -L -800G /dev/ubuntu-vg/root

sudo pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sda2:yyyy-end
```

Then I could resize my partitions in gparted. Pvmove was necessary because the free space needed to be moved to the end of the partition, as described in the linked solution.

[Edit] Plot twist - After resizing my partition with gparted, the LVM partition no longer works, and my grub installation is broken. Now I just boot into my default OS (ubuntu 18.04) and can no longer access the LVM partition. It tells me

"error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/mars/: wrong fs type, pad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

Not a very helpful error message tbh. I thought LVM was supposed to make the process of resizing partitions easier, but it also makes the process of destroying your partitions eaiser too. I ran a bunch of diagnostics but don't have time to update here just yet, will update again over the weekend.